# Computing cluster power loss: filesystems no longer available. Possible causes?

Tags: centos, filesystems

Firstly, I am not a system admin, but only a user. Our IT department has had significant turnover and the current staff are not knowledgeable of our HPC system, nor can they currently provide assistance.

That said, I am using a high performance computing cluster that is running on CentOS Linux 7. Our cluster recently lost power due to a storm. **Before** power loss, a df command provided output like this:

```
Filesystem                 1K-blocks         Used   Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/md4                   723772952     48291720   675481232   7% /
devtmpfs                    32828496            0    32828496   0% /dev
tmpfs                       32844812            4    32844808   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                       32844812      1010484    31834328   4% /run
tmpfs                       32844812            0    32844812   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md3                    31425544      4035716    27389828  13% /var
/dev/md2                     8370176        33068     8337108   1% /tmp
/dev/md123                    507684       149533      331940  32% /boot
182.22.0.47:/pool0/data  57316467200          256 57316466944   1% /data
182.22.0.47:/pool0/home 172707177472 115390709760 57316467712  67% /home
tmpfs                        6568964           12     6568952   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                        6568964            0     6568964   0% /run/user/1003
```

The home directories for all users are located on the filesystem 182.22.0.47:/pool0/home. However, after we lost power and regained it, I tried a df command which yielded the following output:

```
Filesystem                 1K-blocks         Used   Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/md4                   723772952     48291720   675481232   7% /
devtmpfs                    32828496            0    32828496   0% /dev
tmpfs                       32844812            4    32844808   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                       32844812      1010484    31834328   4% /run
tmpfs                       32844812            0    32844812   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md3                    31425544      4035716    27389828  13% /var
/dev/md2                     8370176        33068     8337108   1% /tmp
/dev/md123                    507684       149533      331940  32% /boot
tmpfs                        6568964           12     6568952   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                        6568964            0     6568964   0% /run/user/1003
```

The output is identical except for the missing filesystems that begin with the IP address 182.22.0.47.

I want to figure out the following: why are these filesystems no longer mounting? At first I thought that the node at 182.22.0.47 simply has no power. However, I can SSH into it this node no problem. However after doing so, I am unable to find the user home directories. Furthermore, the disk capacity (~450 GB) is far below the original capacity given in the first df output (~161 TB).

I am happy to provide more information if possible. As I mentioned, I am only a user and not a system admin so I am limited in what I can try. Thank you for your time.

**EDIT**: To answer the comment, I am not sure. Can you please clarify? This is admittedly not in my wheelhouse.

However, since posting the question, I've found that the remote node may actually have over 200 TB of unmounted storage (which hopefully contains the missing data). I discovered this with an lsblk command which produced the following output:

```
    NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
    sda           8:0    0 745.2G  0 disk  
    ├─sda1        8:1    0 745.2G  0 part  
    └─sda9        8:9    0     8M  0 part  
    sdb           8:16   0  93.2G  0 disk  
    ├─sdb1        8:17   0  93.2G  0 part  
    └─sdb9        8:25   0     8M  0 part  
    sdc           8:32   0  93.2G  0 disk  
    ├─sdc1        8:33   0  93.2G  0 part  
    └─sdc9        8:41   0     8M  0 part  
    sdd           8:48   0 745.2G  0 disk  
    ├─sdd1        8:49   0 745.2G  0 part  
    └─sdd9        8:57   0     8M  0 part  
    sde           8:64   0 447.1G  0 disk  
    └─md126       9:126  0 424.8G  0 raid1 
      ├─md126p1 259:0    0   500M  0 md    /boot
      ├─md126p2 259:1    0   3.9G  0 md    [SWAP]
      └─md126p3 259:2    0 420.4G  0 md    /
    sdf           8:80   0   5.5T  0 disk  
    ├─sdf1        8:81   0   5.5T  0 part  
    └─sdf9        8:89   0    64M  0 part  
    sdg           8:96   0   5.5T  0 disk  
                       .
                       .
                       .
```

I am thinking that the problem is simply unmounted filesystem(s), though I'm not sure.

Comment: Can you check if the remote system is still sharing those resources? Please don't answer in a comment but update your question instead.

Comment: I was playing around with NFS recently, https://serverfault.com/questions/1076206/nfs-server-is-exporting-shares-but-is-not As you can see I'm clearly no expert either, but you'll find there commands to check whether resources are exported in local or remote device. There's also how to create exports, but I'd strongly recommend verifying those before applying in a production environment! If the filesystems weren't mounted in the first place I assume sharing wouldn't happen either so I hope your lost data is on those unmounted filesystems. Best of luck!

Comment: Are they auto mounted? Try doing a `cd` to each of /data and /home.

Comment: I don't think so. The contents of the 182.22.0.47:/pool0/data and 182.22.0.47:/pool0/home directories are empty.

Comment: Just as an aside, you did an excellent job formulating your question, but the management in charge of your IT department should be fired immediately, or the IT department itself, trying to run this type of complex situation without competent admins and making you try to figure it out for yourself is serial incompetence of the highest order.  I tend to agree, looks like a mount failure however. Whatever you do, don't do anything without understanding exactly what you are doing and why, otherwise the situation can get much worse. Better, call IT consultant, fire IT staff.

Comment: LOL - @Lizardx ain't one to mince his words :-D Have to say I wholeheartedly agree.

Comment: It may not be incompetence (at least not on the part of the IT staff, blame the penny-pinching bean-counters).  Many universities go through recurring cycles of centralising IT, sacking all the faculty/department staff (who have all the institutional knowledge) or transferring them to central IT.  Central IT invariably only does desktop support for Windows, MS Word and Excel and the like.  Research groups quickly realise this sucks for them and start hiring their own IT staff, and the cycle begins again.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments and insight! It's definitely given me a good starting point.